# Is it possible to change the contents of "the_content()"?

Tags: the-content

I have moved a blog over to wordpress and I've used a lot of DOMDocument, xpath, regex and other methods to scrub the text.

This means that `the_content();` is no longer the content and I'm using my own function 'stripped_content();' to echo out my stuff.

I have a plugin that looks for `the_content();` and puts some social media buttons beneath it, but obviously my posts no longer use it.

So how can I make `the_content();` my new content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Add a filter to `the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) and put your code in there so you don't need your custom content function:

```
function wpa_content_filter( $content ) {
    // run your code on $content and
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpa_content_filter' );
```

You may need to adjust priority to run your filter before or after others:

```
// high priority, run early
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpa_content_filter' 1 );

// low priority, run late
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpa_content_filter' 999 );
```

Comment: Thanks, so instead of this `$html = mb_convert_encoding($post->post_content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");` would I now do this `$html = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");`? and do I return it with `$doc->saveHTML(); return $content;` and then just call `the_content();`?

Comment: you need to return whatever contains the final processed content - if it's the `$html` var, then you `return $html`. then you can just use `the_content()` in your template.