# Where in code to replace content before display of page?

Tags: customization

I wish to make a replacement in all pages of a WordPress installation, after the page content has been read from the database and before it is displayed on visitor screen (of course).

*Where* in the code do I insert the following statement that will  make the replacement?

```
$page = str_replace($target, $replace, $page);
```

I run an updated WordPress using 2016 child theme. Among others I have a dedicated single.php and a functions.php

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the contents of "the\_content()"?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129018/is-it-possible-to-change-the-contents-of-the-content)

Comment: The solutions are similar in both questions. But the questions are somewhat differently put. Maybe both questions should be kept, for easy reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use native editor (and not some PageBuilder that stores data in its way), then you should be able to use [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter to do that:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {

    $content = str_replace(...);

    return $content;
}
```

You might put some conditions in there, to check if you modify only pages or only on single page and so on...

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate. It worked straight out of the box.